# The man who made it didn't want it

Tags: riddle

The man who made it didn't want it.

The man who bought it didn't need it.

The man who got it didn't know it.

What is it?

Explain your reasoning.

Comment: *Your* attempt?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Like people said, it's old and well-known. "Your attempt" makes it sounds like you're saying you invented it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an old one.

> A coffin or casket.

Explanation:

> The man who makes it, doesn't want to use it, the man who bought it isn't the one who it's for, and the man got it, is dead.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is :

> Coffin

It's a well known riddle :-)

> The one who makes it is still alive(probably).
>  The one who buys it is also alive.
>  The one who is dead, and is buried in it doesn't know that he is in the coffin.

Comment: yeah, i figured it would be, but I didn't see it on the site, so I figured what the heck, maybe it's not.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.stackexchange :-)
The fellow puzzlers have solved many riddles like this, we have innate love for puzzles and encourage any puzzle which provides nutrition to brain.

Hope you find your journey enthralling ^_^

Comment: Yeah, I like puzzles, but I think i'm way out of my league. I joined Stack Exchange four days ago, and I'm mostly on Arqade.

Comment: @WalkerNiemeyer I believe it was decided that old puzzles are welcome so we have a set of correct answers to all the classics. Thanks for contributing this one!

Answer (score 0):

I also think it could be an atom bomb.

> The man who made it didn't want it.

They're seen as a necessary evil rather than something wanted

> The man who bought it didn't need it.

When sold to warring countries its to those who don't actually need it.

> The man who got it didn't know it.

There's no real early warning system that works practically, so they'd have no warning

Comment: I guess that would work, but not the answer I was looking for, and rather macabre.

Comment: But it does fit though

Comment: @WalkerNiemeyer - And the intended answer *isn't* macabre?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit this answer to explain how you reached this conclusion given the information in the question?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman not really, much less so than the atom bomb.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a

> coffin?

That fits and is semi-macabre.
The man who made it didn't want it - as in built the coffin and sold it but didn't want it for himself;
The man who bought it didn't want it - as in bought it for his deceased loved one but didn't want it for himself, and hopefully not for his dead loved one;
The man who got it didn't know it - as in that man is dead and couldn't know it.

Just a stab in the dark. The atom bomb reply earlier made me consider something more, uh, unfortunate an item.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit this answer to explain how you reached this conclusion given the information in the question?

Comment: 2 other people (including the accepted answer) have already given this exact answer before you...