# Person who buy me will not use me

Tags: riddle

Someone made me and sold me,

The person who buys me doesn't use me,

The person who will use me, won't know he is using me,

Sooner or later most of the people will use me,

Almost everybody wishes to use me as late as possible,

Who or what am I?

Comment: Im pretty sure this is a duplicate of http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/riddle-of-the-unwanted-present and http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29309/the-man-who-made-it-didnt-want-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer:

> Coffin

Someone made me and sell me,

> No big deal here...someone produces coffins and sells them

person who buy me will not use me,

> usually you don't buy a coffin for yourself. you do it for someone else and someone else will do it for you.

who will use me, will never know he is using me,

> If you need it, you're dead so you don't care anymore

sooner or later everyone will use me,

> I could argue on this one. Not every dead person get's buried, but YES, you are going to die at one point and you might need a coffin.

if you know me who i am, you also wish to use me as late as possible.

> We all want to live a long and prosper life.